# Reconocer variables numeradas Python

Tags: python, variables

Tengo variables con el mismo nombre y numeradas, por ejemplo:

```
list_1 = ["hola", "ejemplo", "prueba"]
list_2 = ["queso", "tv", "domingo"]
```

¿Cómo hago para reconocer todas las variables al mismo tiempo? Algún tipo de wildcard.

```
def search(list_1,x):
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        if list_1[i] == x:
            return True
    return False


list_1 = ["hola", "ejemplo", "prueba"]
list_2 = ["queso", "tv", "domingo"]
      
# Driver Code
x = 'Geeks'
      
if search(list_1, x):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

Funciona con list_1, pero, quiero que haga la busqueda en todas las variables, porque seran muchas.

x sera la palabra que yo buscare.

Comment: Se podría hacer con expresiones regulares, pero no funcionaria de la forma en que quieres

Comment: Cualquier sugerencia/ejemplo/alternativa sera bien recibida.

Comment: Puedes leer esta [pagina](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-implement-wildcards-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando tienes un conjunto de variables con el mismo nombre y diferente "sufijo" como en tu caso, lo que tienes es el síntoma claro de que necesitas una lista o un diccionario.

Si en vez de variables llamadas `lista_1`, `lista_2`, etc tienes una sola variable de tipo `list` llamada `listas`, entonces accederías a cada "sub-variable" por su índice: `listas[0]`, `listas[1]`, etc. o podrás iterar por ellas.

En tu caso la `listas` sería una lista de listas, pero eso no plantea ningún problema:

```
listas = [
   ["hola", "ejemplo", "prueba"],
   ["queso", "tv", "domingo"]
]
```

entonces iterar es trivial:

```
for lista in listas:
  search(lista, x)
```

### Otra solución (de emergencia)

Si por cualquier razón no pudieras reescribir el código para convertirlo en algo como lo anterior (por ejemplo, porque el código te ha sido dado "ya así", con miles de variables de nombres iguales, repartidas por diferentes partes del mismo), siempre puedes usar `globals()`, pero yo consideraría eso una solución de emergencia. Lo correcto sería refactorizar (reescribir) el código para que use listas correctamente.

Respecto a `globals()` es una función predefinida de python que te devuelve un diccionario cuyas claves son los nombres de las variables globales y cuyos valores son los de esas variables (en realidad no contiene solo variables, también funciones, clases, cualquier símbolo definido a nivel global).

Con este truco podrías hacer algo como:

```
todas_las_variables = globals()
for v in todas_las_variables:   # v es una cadena con el nombre de una variable
   if v.startswith("lista_"):
      lista = todas_las_variables[v]     # obtener su valor
      search(lista,x)                    # y usarlo
```

### Nota final

Entiendo que tu ejemplo de la función `search()` era solo eso, un ejemplo, ya que si realmente estás buscando un elemento en una lista no necesitarías programar esa función. Basta mirar `if x in lista`.

Si quieres realizar una búsqueda de una palabra en todas las sublistas, iterarás por un bucle. Si quieres mostrar qué sublista (su índice) es la que contiene la palabra, puedes utilizar `enumerate()` para recorrerlas. Esta función te retorna en cada iteración una tupla con dos valores, el primero es el índice y el segundo la sublista.

Entonces:

```
for indice, sublista in enumerate(listas):
  if palabra in sublista:
    print("Palabra encontrada en sublista", indice)
```

Si necesitas que la comparación de la palabra con la sublista sea "insensible al caso" (por ejemplo que se pase todo a minúsculas antes de comparar), la cosa se complica un poquito, porque entonces tendrías que pasar a minúsculas todas las palabras en la `sublista`, lo que te obliga a iterar por ella para pasar todo a minúsculas y después usar el operador `in` para ver si la palabra está. La idea sería esta:

```
for indice, sublista in enumerate(listas):
  sublista_minusculas = [ palabra.lower() for palabra in sublista ]
  if palabra.lower() in sublista_minusculas:
    print("Palabra encontrada en sublista", indice)
```

Sin embargo en este caso ya no es tan eficiente el uso de `in`, ya que para poder usarlo hemos tenido que convertir antes **todas** las palabras de la sublista. Imagina que la palabra que buscabas era la primera, y que la sublista tenía 200 palabras. Entonces el enfoque anterior habría perdido el tiempo pasando a minúsculas 200 palabras pues la que se buscaba era la primera y las otras 199 no eran necesarias.

Para optimizar mejor este caso se puede iterar sobre la sublista, elemento a elemento, pasando cada uno a minúsculas y comparándolo con la palabra, deteniéndose en cuanto se encuentre una coincidencia (evitando así tener que pasar a minúsculas el resto de palabras de esa subcadena).

```
for indice, sublista in enumerate(listas):
  for p in sublista:
    if palabra.lower() == p.lower():
        print("Palabra encontrada en sublista", indice)
        break
```

El `break` causa que se abandone el bucle `for` más interno (es decir, se deja de mirar palabras de esa sublista) y se pasa a la siguiente iteración del bucle externo (es decir, se va a por la siguiente sublista).

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Veo que lo correcto si es usar sublistas, pero, como hago para buscarlas? Nota: se que con print(listas[21]) llego a una exacta, pero, como hago una compracion o busqueda masiva.

Comment: Con lo que me pusiste arriba me sale el error de NameError: name 'search' is not defined

Comment: Me he basado en tu ejemplo, en el que definías más arriba una función `search()`. Si no la tienes obviamente no funcionará. Aunque realmente si lo que quieres es mirar si una palabra dada está en cualquiera de las listas no necesitarías ni siquiera implementar esa función, como también te indico al final de la respuesta. Bastaría un `for lista in listas: if "Geeks" in lista: print("Found")`

Comment: Tengo un conjunto de sublistas, ademas de identificar una palabra en las sublistas quiero poder saber el indice de esa sublista cuando encuentro esa palabra.

Comment: Quieres decir que aunque los contenidos de las sublistas estén en mayúsculas, la comparación quieres hacerla en minúsculas?

Comment: Ok, ampliación ampliada de nuevo :-)

Answer (score 1):

no le veo la utilidad al código que deseas realizar pero me parece que una forma sería:

```
variable_1 = "01"
variable_2 = "02"
variable_3 = "03"
variable_4 = "04"


var_1 = "01"
var_2 = "02"
var_3 = "03"
var_5 = "04"

num_1 = 1
num_2 = 2
num_3 = 3
num_4 = 4

for x in range(1,5):
    v1 = f"variable_{x}"
    v2 = f"var_{x}"
    if v1 in locals() and v2 in locals():
        print(locals().get(v2))
```

agregue valores para que recorra todas e hice una diferente para que no la encuentre.
Otra cosa muy importante, no se puede declarar enteros que comiencen con 0 , por eso las primeras variables las declaré como cadenas, para enteros deben ser declaradas como las últimas variables num

Editada:

como has cambiado todo el código,¿por qué no lo pusiste antes?

basicamente es lo mismo y se puede aplicar de muchas maneras, una de ellas es la siguiente:

```
def search(lista,valor):
    for i in lista:
        if i == valor:
            return True
    return False


list_1 = ["hola", "ejemplo", "prueba"]
list_2 = ["queso", "tv", "domingo"]


dato = 'Geeks'

  
for x in range(1,3):
    lista=locals().get(f"list_{x}")
    if search(lista, dato):
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

el resto es cuestión de un poco de imaginación a como aplicarlo en los cambios que realices.

Otra cosa ¿por qué directamente no haces una lista con sublistas?

Comment: Usar variables numeradas es una discapacidad mental.

Comment: no se puede esperar otra cosa de quien viene el comentario que agresiones gratuitas, le recomendé que use una lista y sublistas mucho antes que abulafia, pero se ve que no le importó lo que le dije..

Answer (score 1):

La palabra clave in tiene dos propósitos:

- Se usa para verificar si un valor está presente
  en una secuencia (lista, rango, cadena, etc.).
- También se usa para iterar a través de una
  secuencia en un bucle for.

En este caso ocupamos el primer uso:

```
list_1 = ["hola", "ejemplo", "prueba"]
list_2 = ["queso", "tv", "domingo"]
  
# Driver Code
x = 'Geeks'
# Concatenamos las listas
list_3 = list_1 + list_2

# Buscamos con "in"   
if x in list_3:
     print("Found")
else:
     print("Not Found")
```

Comment: Agrega más contexto a tu respuesta: ¿qué hace el código? Lee [answer].